# Facebook Ads API error: must be a valid custom audience id

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Unlike targeting a `custom audience`, it seems impossible to create an ad targeting a `saved audience` using [Facebook Ads API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs/v2.9). Can someone confirm that is the case? What would be a workaround? This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error #100: Param targeting[custom_audiences][id] must be a valid custom audience id
```

There is a difference between a `saved audience` and a `custom audience`. A `saved audience` is an audience you manually create specifying age range, geographic region and interests. While a `custom audience` is a list of customers you gathered (uploaded or visitors or your site etc). You can create these audiences manually through the Ads Manager interface:

[image]

Using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), one can retrieve `saved audiences` as follow:

```
act_1234567890/saved_audiences
```

[image]

Using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), one can retrieve `custom audiences` as follow:

```
act_123456789/customaudiences
```

[image]

*Note that `123456789` is not my real account number. I changed it for security reasons.*

So, I can retrieve IDs for both `custom audiences` and `saved audiences` and creating an ad targeting a `custom audience` works fine, unlike targeting a `saved audience` which gives the above error message.

A cumbersome workaround could be to save the [`flexible_spec`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs/v2.9#flexible) of each `saved audience` locally and use that spec when creating ads. The problem with that is that some `targeting segments` become invalid (Facebook decides to discontinue some segments at random times) which causes Facebook Ads API to hickup. Additionally, this means I constantly need to keep `saved audiences` in sync with my local copy. Unless of course I retrieve the `targeting` of a `saved audience` on the fly and re-use it, each time I create an ad resulting in yet another API request.

Comment: bart can you say what you mean by a saved audience?

Comment: @aks I've added a ton of more detail to the question showing the difference between custom and saved audiences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. It seems impossible to directly target a `saved audience` unlike a `custom audience`, which is odd. What I did is retrieve the `targeting` from the saved audience first and reuse that targeting when creating the ad.

Here you see a screenshot of the official documentation showing only `custom audiences` and `lookalike audiences` can be targeted.

[image]

Retrieving `targeting` from `saved audience` (with Facebook PHP SDK):

```
$api = Api::instance();

use FacebookAds\Http\Request;

$response = $api->call(
  "/987654321", 'GET',
  array('fields'=>'targeting')
);
$audience = $response->getContent();
```

*With 987654321 as the saved audience ID.*

Then copy that targeting to the ad (with Facebook PHP SDK):

```
use FacebookAds\Object\Targeting;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\TargetingFields;

$targeting = new Targeting();
$targeting->setData($audience['targeting']);
```

The disadvantage of this technique is that the ad won't be updated when the `saved audience` is updated and that it requires an extra API call which slows down the creation of the ad.

Comment: can you please elobrate your answer, i am getting still this error in version 5.0

Comment: @HammadulHasan How can I elaborate? What is that you don't understand?

Comment: i am also want to use saved audience but getting same error, and also i am getting error to read the saved audience to get to targeting data that i can use in my targeting, using nodejs